# Replacing first line of csv file and importing to SAS

Tags: performance, csv, import, sas

I have many large csv files where the first row must be modified to remove/replace certain characters. I import them by looping over each file, creating a temp version of the csv and importing it to SAS, and then appending it to a master table.

The part where I where modify the csv file and create a temp version of it takes too long. Here's what I do:

Sample/pseudo code:

```
for file in files:
data _null_;
  infile file delimiter = "|";
  file  ”temp.csv”;
  input @;
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    _infile_ = compress(_infile_, "/.()"); * removing the following characters: [ () / . ];
    _infile_ = tranwrd(_infile_,' ','_'); * replacing blanks with underscores;
  end;
  put _infile_ ;
run;
```

This approach is inefficient because only the first row is modified, but all rows of the file are processed (Essentially I am making a copy of the file). Is it possible do this more efficiently? I was thinking something along the lines of:

1. Read only first line of csv file and save the modified row to a global variable
2. Open the original csv and replace first row, then save "as is"

Here's the code for part 1, but I haven't figured how to do part 2 efficiently. Any suggestions?

```
%global firstRow;
data _null_;
  infile filedelimiter = "|" obs=1; *reading only first row I.E. variable names;
  input @;
    _infile_ = compress(_infile_, "/.()"); * removing the following characters: [ () / . ];
    _infile_ = tranwrd(_infile_,' ','_'); * replacing blanks with underscores;
    call symput("firstRow", _infile_);
    putlog _infile_;
run;
%put &firstRow;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "import".  To convert a delimited text file into a dataset just use a data step.  You can then modify the first line while you are making the dataset, no need to make a copy of the text file.

Comment: By import I mean reading a csv file to sas. Could you provide some code? The reason I am modifying the text file directly is because I was unable to read it in to SAS due to some odd characters in the first row.

Comment: Why would the characters cause trouble reading the file? Is the first line a header row or part of the data?  If it is a header row then just skip it.  Write your own data step to read it and create your own names for the variables you create.

Comment: What is the problem that the first line is causing? Show an example of two or three lines of the CSV file.  Does not need to be the real data, just something that you can use to demonstrate the problem it is causing you.

Answer (score 0):

Normally the first line of a CSV file is just a header line.  So when you read the data into a dataset you skip the header line.  Why would you need to modify it?

Here is an example of a data step for reading a pipe delimited text file to give you the idea of how to structure your program to read your file.

```
 data want;
   infile 'myfile.csv' dsd dlm='|' truncover firstobs=2;
   input var1 :$20. var2 var3 :date. ;
   format var3 date9.;
 run;
```